# Show random div onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, variables

I am making a little project. For this project I want to be able to show a div to visitors of my site. However, I want my content to be varying. I've created three divs, all with a different id. When someone enters my site, I want him/her to see just one of the three divs. I've created some code that I thought would do the trick, but obviously it did not. I would really appreciate it if someone could tell me where I'm doing it wrong.

**HTML**

```
<div id="one">
1
</div>

<div id="two">
2
</div>

<div id="three">
3
</div>

<input type="button" id="Button" value="Random" onclick="RandomDiv();" />
```

**CSS**

```
#one {
    display:none;
}

#two {
    display:none;
}

#three {
    display:none;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function RandomDiv() {
    var myarray= new Array("one","two","three");
    var ChosenDiv = myarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray.length)];
    alert(ChosenDiv); //Just to show this.
    document.getElementbyId(ChosenDiv).style.display="inline-block";
}
```

Now, the alert seems to work fine, so that means that there is no problem in deciding the "ChosenDiv" (one, two or three). However, when I want to make that chosen div visible (`display:none` -> `display:inline-block`), it simply won't do this. I tried to use Google Chrome for defining the problem, but I can't tell what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do answers always have to be so overcomplicated?

Just run the code, check your console and find out that you're using `getElementbyId` and not `getElementById` with a capital `b`, it's basic problem solving?

`TypeError: document.getElementbyId is not a function[Learn More]  script.js:6:5`

jQuery is way to much to put into your project to simply edit some CSS or select some simple elements, if you ask me.

Comment: Thank you! Must 've been quite stupid not seeing this. I saw that it said that indeed, but couldn't figure out the problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery can help with changing CSS in javascript.

See http://api.jquery.com/css/ for more information on how to use this.

```
function RandomDiv() {
  var myarray= new Array("one","two","three");
  var ChosenDiv = myarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray.length)];
  alert(ChosenDiv); //Just to show this.
  document.getElementById(ChosenDiv).css("display":"inline-block");
}
```

Don't forget to include jQuery in your code!

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Will this code run or should it include something like `<body onload="RandomDiv()">` (without JQuery)?

Comment: I'm not sure how Syan was using this is his application. I've just edited his code from above. To run this code you'll either need to move the code outside a function or trigger it from a button or link.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert values in your array to this format:

```
var myarray= new Array("#one","#two","#three");
```

Comment: that would make it get element by id of "#one". He is doing it correctly of that part

Answer (score 0):

Just use a new function to call the display, lumping it in with your randomiser is one way to get a whole mess of bugs, and as previously mentioned, it seems you need to check your capitalisation, it's important